# Extend generated TestApp to verify pyqt5 button click

Tags: python, mocking, pyqt5, pytest

I would like to create a test function for a pyqt5 button click verification.

I use the following code to create the button app:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100 ,70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')
        # mock this call: startMotor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I use pycharm as IDE. It offers to create a test for my App-Class and generates the following code:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestApp(TestCase):
    def test_on_click(self):
        self.fail()
```

I have tried to use libs like pytest, pytest-mock, pytestqt to

1. Let the test click the button
2. Verify the button click event
3. Mock the action of the button but could not make it work in any way.

The libs documentations only show code snippets but I do not know where to place them into my TestApp class.

Can you show me how to extend the generated test code to achieve above points?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your app module is called `myapp.py` and you use `self.button` in `initUI`:

#### `unittest`

```python
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest

from myapp import App


class TestApp(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = QApplication([])

    def test_on_click(self):
        with mock.patch("myapp.App.on_click") as fake_on_click:
            app = App()
            QTest.mouseClick(app.button, Qt.LeftButton)
            self.assertTrue(fake_on_click.called)
```

#### `pytest`

The logic is the same, but assertions can be done with `assert` keyword and no class is needed. The `QApplication` singleton can be conveniently moved out to a fixture.

```python
from unittest import mock
import pytest
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest

from myapp import App


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def ctx():
    return QApplication([])


def test_on_click():
    with mock.patch("myapp.App.on_click") as fake_on_click:
        app = App()
        QTest.mouseClick(app.button, Qt.LeftButton)
        assert fake_on_click.called
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, hoefling, both methods do what I wanted and it looks much less complicated than I imagined! The only thing I am puzzled about is how setUp or ctx() is called?

Comment: @juerg both are parts of the respective testing frameworks. If [`TestCase.setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) is present in class, it is called automatically on each test method setup. Similarly, a [`pytest.fixture`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) is called automatically before each test function if [`autouse=True`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request) is configured.